# Create a Label or Tab using only CSS

Tags: css

I would like to create a tab or label like look using only CSS and no images if possible. Here is what I mean:

[image: Label]

I can create one end but I have not been able to create the triangle point. Is it possible to do this with only CSS?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are indeed ways to create CSS triangles, here's a part from css-tricks.com:

```
.arrow-right {
   width: 0; 
   height: 0; 
   border-top: 60px solid transparent;
   border-bottom: 60px solid transparent;
   border-left: 60px solid green;
}
```

http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/css-triangle/

Answer (score 2):

HTML

```
<div class="arrow-left"></div>
<div class="arrow-body"></div>
```

CSS

```
.arrow-left {   float:left;  width: 0;      height: 0;      border-top: 20px solid transparent;     border-bottom: 20px solid transparent;           border-right:20px solid blue;  }
.arrow-body{ float:left; width:200px; height:40px;  background-color:Blue;}
```

Answer (score 2):

Yes, but not while supporting IE7:

```
<a class="tab">Your label text</a>

.tab {
    background: black;
    border-top-right-radius: 3px;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 3px;
    position: relative;
}
.tab::before {
    content: " ";
    position: absolute;
    right: 100%;
    top: 0;
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    border-width: 35px; /* play with this value to match the height of the tab */
    border-style: solid;
    border-color: transparent black transparent transparent;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is another one

```
<div></div>​
```

```css
div{
    width:500px;
    height:100px;
    background-color:black;
    border-top-right-radius:10px;
    border-bottom-right-radius:10px;
    margin-left:100px;
}
div:before{
    width:0;
    height:0;
    content:"";
    display:inline-block;
    border-top:50px solid transparent;
    border-right:100px solid black;
    border-bottom:50px solid transparent;
    position:absolute;
    left:0;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/e8feE/