# Create a label shape with rounded corners and box-shadow, using CSS?

Tags: css

I need to implement this

[image]

I took a look at this post which is very similar to mine [Create a Label or Tab using only CSS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12906200/create-a-label-or-tab-using-only-css)

The problem with the solutions provided there is that I need to apply box-shadow to the contour of the label as shown in the image, which doesn't work If I use the typically recommended ways of doing a triangle, using border tricks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Couldn't find a clean neat way of doing it with CSS only, but this worked for me:

```css
    .tag-wrap {
    filter: drop-shadow(0px 0px 12px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15));
    }

    .tag {
    clip-path: url(#svgPath);
    height: 70px;
    width: 163px;
    display: flex;
    padding: 0 5px 0 25px;
    align-items: center;
    background-color: white;
    line-height: normal;
    }
```

```html
  <svg height="0" width="0">
    <defs>
      <clipPath id="svgPath" clipPathUnits="objectBoundingBox">
        <path d="M 0.0997 0.0817 C 0.1081 0.0425 0.1243 0.0182 0.1419 0.0182 H 0.196 L 0.2666 0.0182 L 0.3466 0.0182 H 0.9346 C 0.961 0.0182 0.9825 0.0719 0.9825 0.1382 V 0.8585 C 0.9825 0.9249 0.961 0.9786 0.9346 0.9786 H 0.1411 C 0.1239 0.9786 0.108 0.9555 0.0995 0.918 L 0.024 0.5854 C 0.0138 0.5406 0.0136 0.4858 0.0233 0.4403 L 0.0997 0.0817 Z" />
      </clipPath>
    </defs>
  </svg>

  <div class="tag-wrap">
    <div class="tag">Some text here</div>
  </div>
```

First I started with this: https://css-tricks.com/using-box-shadows-and-clip-path-together/

Then used this tool https://yqnn.github.io/svg-path-editor/ to replicate the shape I needed as closely as possible and get its SVG Path.

[image]

Then rescaled it so that the coordinates are all between 0 and 1. This is needed for `clipPathUnits="objectBoundingBox"` to work, which makes the SVG scale according to the size of the parent.

[image]